# R.layout Android 2.2.3

Tags: android

Why am i having to go all the way in my class so he can recognize this layout i created? Because it simply does not recognize as `R.layout.my_layout`

OK:

```
super(context, com.example.leonardoinhoqui.tcc2.R.layout.my_layout);
```

Problem:

```
super(context,R.layout.my_layout);
```

Comment: add `import com.example.leonardoinhoqui.tcc2.R;` in your imports and then `super(context,R.layout.my_layout);` will work. Even then if it doesn't work, then there might be some faults in any of your Layout files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have a wrong `import` in your code (this sometimes happen when Android Studio resolves imports)

```
 import android.R.*;
```

and because of that you have to provide the full name of your own R package

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve :) ... I'm starting now on android.